# Access pipeline A´s variables from pipeline B... Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cicd

After some internet search, I wasnt able to find a proper way or suggestion on how to access variables from different pipelines. Lets say, from Pipeline A access variables of Pipeline B.
What I did find, is the idea to use Key Vault, which I am not able to use right now. I was wondering if there is a workaround, lets say, with powershell.

All of this is happening in an Azure Devops environment, where I am trying to access/read variables from different pipelines.

Any ideas?

Kind regards

Leo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of variable groups to call variables in multiple pipelines within a project.

You just need to reference that variable in the YAML script or release pipeline with the variable group and use it in any pipeline, Refer below :-

*I went to my project > Pipelines > Library > Variable Group > And added a variable > You can add multiple variables here storing your secrets or values.*

[image]

[image]

[image]

Using the variable group in a yaml pipeline :-

```yaml
    trigger:
    - main
    pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    variables:
    - group: SharedVariables
    steps:
    - script: |
    echo $(databaseserverpassword)
```

[image]

Now, when you run the pipeline, It will ask you to permit the use of variable group for the pipeline.

**This will enable access to all the variables in the SharedVariables group.**

[image]

[image]

Output :-

[image]

We got our databaseservername value masked.

You can also enable this variable group for all the pipeline in the project by default.

[image]

You can use the same variable group in your Classic pipeline or release pipeline in release or specific stages like below :-

[image]

Reference :-

[Variable groups for Azure Pipelines - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

For PowerShell - [Azure DevOps: how to manage CI/CD variable groups using PowerShell – Radu Narita (ranari.com)](https://ranari.com/2020/03/26/devops-manage-variable-groups-powershell/#:%7E:text=To%20create%20or%20update%20a%20variable%20in%20a,to%20Variables%20Tabs%2C%20and%20then%20select%20%E2%80%9CVariable%20Groups.%E2%80%9D)